# How to add additional installer to start menu using ClickOnce

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have created a solution that comprise of a WPF application and a mobile device application. What I am trying to figure out is how to facilitate the installation of the mobile application.

When I publish and install the WPF desktop application it creates a start menu folder for the application. Optimally I would like to add the mobile application .msi to this menu but I'm not sure if this is supported by ClickOnce.

Any advice or guidance would be most hopeful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at Inno Setup. Its a free installer for windows applications and has a simple scripting/wizard process. It'll provide this and all the normal installer functions (install location, start menu, desktop icon etc). It also provides an uninstaller